# Drivers and Vehicles information Datasets

Tags: data-request, cars, privacy

Where can I find datasets which contain basic info about drivers and their cars? In details, I'm interested in

- Driver's sex
- Driver's experience (years)
- Driver's profession
- Car's basic info (company/model)
- Car's type (sport/passenger/truck etc.)
- Car's cost
- Car's age
- Type of ownership

Comment: Are you looking for data from a specific jurisdiction or just realistic sample data?

Comment: @DGinzberg  I need just sample data for study project.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the UK driving licencing agency site here:
https://data.gov.uk/dataset

Answer (score 0):

I'm in NC: NC DOT or DMV have data, but you'd need a dua/dsa. You could also try crash data, or the national highway transportation survey. Or the acs daytime estimates for driving patterns at the macro level.

But it sounds like you want car registration data. I've only seen that private, but you might try your state (US?) Dot or DMV and ask for a deidentified data set.

Comment: Just to add on: the US traffic fatality system does allow you to query by age, sex, etc. as well as vehicle info - https://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/QueryTool/QuerySection/SelectOptions.aspx - but you should be careful to think about how fatality data could correlate or not correlate to all drivers.